How do I add pagination to the swiper slider activity class?
enter image description here
How to add an activity class to a viewed pagination and vice versa remove it when you return to it
Sweeper slider
Maybe you can make a custom progress bar somehow
I would be very grateful for writing a function
Here is my code
var swiper = new Swiper(".repair-calc_slider", {
navigation: {
  nextEl: ".repair-calc-next",
  prevEl: ".repair-calc-prev",
},
pagination: {
    el: ".repair-calc-pagination",
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + "</span>";
    },
  },

});

I think your best bet is to use the slideChange SwiperEvent
var swiper = new Swiper(".repair-calc_slider", {
navigation: {
    nextEl: ".repair-calc-next",
    prevEl: ".repair-calc-prev",
},
pagination: {
    el: ".repair-calc-pagination",
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
        return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + "</span>";
    },
},
on: {
    slideChange: function () {
        var activeIndex = this.activeIndex;
        var bullets = document.querySelectorAll('.repair-calc-pagination span');
        bullets.forEach((bullet, index) => {
            if (index < activeIndex) {
                bullet.classList.add('completed');
            } else {
                bullet.classList.remove('completed');
            }
        });
    },
},
});


sorry, we need an active pagination class

Please could you possibly provide a bit more information on what it is you want to see as the output?

According to the link in the question, there is a photo of what needs to be done marked with red lines. There is pagination and when scrolling through the slide, you need to add activity classes to the pagination and also delete if you scroll back

AHHHH I see what you mean now, I'll have a think and try to get back to you

Updated, hope that does the trick
